# HTML post php variable to form as additional data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am setting up a users-only page, where the users can access a database.
I require the form they use to add things to the database to grab their name from the users database, which was accessed earlier in the document to verify their account, and place it in a column labeled Added By for that new row.

So, I'm using the following code
`<script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                $.post("insert.php",{"name":"Keegan"});});
            </script>`
Which works well for putting my name through, but i can't figure out how to get the variable out of the above php tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
<script>
  var r = <?php echo $thename; ?>;
</script>
```

or this:

```
 <?php
    echo '<script>var r = ' . $thename . ';</script>';
  ?>
```